# start non-root user systemd and systemd services via sudo without enable-linger

Tags: sudo, systemd, dbus

I'm like to be able to start a `systemd` session (e.g. `systemd --user`) for a given non-root user, and subsequently start a service (e.g. `systemctl --user start SERVICE.service`), all via a `sudo -iu USER` session, but without using `loginctl enable-linger USER` prior to that `sudo` invocation.

I know that if I were to `ssh USER@host`, PAM would happily create/start a `systemd` "session" for me, but I don't want nor can't use `ssh`.   I also know that I could use `loginctl enable-linger USER`, but I don't want to do that either.

However, if the USER is already logged in, I'd like to use the existing session instead of starting a new one.  What I want is something like this:

```bash
sudo -iu USER     # or possibly sudo -su USER
# then in sudo subshell...

# setup pointers to correct DBUS session:
export XDG_RUNTIME_DIR="/run/user/$(id -u)"
export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS="unix:path=${XDG_RUNTIME_DIR}/bus"

# then start a systemd session, if not already running
loginctl show-user $(id -u) || systemd --user
```

Unfortunately, the `systemd --user` command errors out with something like:

```
Failed to create /user.slice/user-NNN.slice/session-NNN.scope/init.scope control group: Permission denied
Failed to allocate manager object: Permission denied
```

What am I missing?  Clearly `pam_systemd` does what I want when headless/`ssh` sessions are started.  I'm probably missing some fundamental piece of knowledge, so pointers to relevant docs are also desired, though I've already read most of the relevant man pages, I think.

For extra credit -- just like `pam_systemd`, if a session is not already running, and we have to start one, then that session should automatically be shutdown when the `sudo` session ends.